# How to move the HDFS namenode to a new host

Tags: apache, hadoop, hdfs

what are the correct steps to move a primary Hadoop DFS namenode from one host to another?

I use the version 2.7.1 of hadoop on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS  (without YARN).

Steps done:

- Copy the whole hadoop directory to the new host
- set the new master in $hadoop_home/etc/hadoop/master
- updated the fs.default.name tag in $hadoop_home/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
- formatted the new namenode with the ClusterID of the old namenode: $hadoop_home//bin/hadoop namenode -format -custerId $CLUSTER_ID (I removed the slaves from the config just to be sure that none of the slaves are affected; maybe that is a problem?)

Problem is that the datanodes still don't come up because of the mismatch of the clusterid:

```
2016-03-30 16:20:28,718 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /storage/data: namenode clusterID = CID-c19c691d-10da-4449-a7b6-c953465ce237; datanode clusterID = CID-af87cb62-d806-41d6-9638-e9e559dd3ed7
2016-03-30 16:20:28,718 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to XXXXXXXXXXXXXX. Exiting.
java.io.IOException: All specified directories are failed to load.
```

Any suggestions?
Do I have to add the BlockPool-ID as well?

Answer (score 2):

So I finally managed to get it moved.

- Set the running HDFS into safemode:
  bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode enter
- TarBall the complete directory under dfs.name.dir
- Move the TarBall to the new namenode and extract the contents.
- change the core-site.xml and the master to the hostname of the new node
- start and leave the safemode:
  bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave

Comment: Instead of `tar`ing, `rsync`ing also just worked fine for me for both the `$HADOOP_HOME` and the checkpoint directory.